# How to install android application mobile phone from my PC?

Tags: android, mobile

I got android app on my PC. I would like to install this app on my mobile phone. My mobile phone and PC are using the same Wi-Fi. How can I install this app? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

If Your app is an apk file than u can just share that file from your phone through zapya file share or through usb data cable and click that file it will be installed.If its an app on play store than you can download it from there.